# Firebase: datasnapshot.getValue(className) not working

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm new to Firebase. I try to get data from `dataSnapshot` by using `getValue(className)`. But no matter I try object return `null`.

I got my class and directories like below

Model: `packageName/Models/TongTin.class`

Activity: `packageName/Activities/MainActivity.class`

Here my model code:

```
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class TongTin {

private String type;
private String lotPrice;
private String note;
private String user_uid;
private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

public TongTin() {

}

public TongTin(String type, String lotPrice, String note, String user_uid) {
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    this.type = type;
    this.lotPrice = lotPrice;
    this.note = note;
    this.user_uid = user_uid;
}

public String getUserUid() {
    return user_uid;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public String getNote() {
    return note;
}

public void addTongTin() {
    String key = databaseReference.child(TongTinTable.tableName).push().getKey();
    Map<String,Object> postValues=toMap();
    Map<String,Object> childUpdates=new HashMap<>();
    childUpdates.put(TongTinTable.postURL+key,postValues);
    databaseReference.updateChildren(childUpdates);
}

}
```

Here onDataChange():

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    TongTin tongTin = dataSnapshot.getValue(TongTin.class);
    Log.d("Tong Tin",tongTin.getNote());
}
```

Comment: I don't think you should store `DatabaseReference` inside of your Model classes

Comment: ohh! i use it to add new object to firebase using addTongTin(). I edited my model class.

Comment: Sure, but you do not need it within `class TongTin` to do that. Firebase thinks it needs to deserialize that object from `dataSnapshot.getValue`, but it can't, and so you get null as your object

Comment: wew... really? let's me try to remove it.

Comment: I remove    DatabaseReference  from model class and put it as parameter in addTongTin() but it still return null

Comment: Can you show a screen shot of the Firebase data?

Comment: Sorry i think can't upload image. but my data structure below:

    tong_tins:{
        "slnwoenosdnsdfsdf":{
              type:"weekly",
              note:"something"
        }
    }

Comment: Might be case that you're getting back collection...if so you'll need to do something like `for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {`

Comment: ok let's me try the loop

Comment: I think you need a `getReference("long_tins")` and then `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` from that

Comment: Ohh it really the collection. Thank you very much guys. And how can i mark @JohnO'Reilly answer as accepted answer?

Comment: @KaJasB not sure if that's possible....have posted my comment as answer below instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might be case that you're getting back collection...if so you'll need to do something like

```
for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
```